# linear programming, maximization

Tags: c#, linear-programming, solver, or-tools

> The problem is finding an exact solution to this linear equation
>
> max  = 1411 + 3932 + 2733 + 8044 + 1755
>
> 31 + 52 + 23 + 54 + 45 ≤ 36
>
> 71 + 122 + 113 + 104 ≤ 21
>
> − 32 + 123 + 74 + 25 ≤ 17
>
> 0 ≤ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ≤ 20

> Is anyone able to rewrite this script or suggest a different one?
>
> This program shows results but is inaccurate.
> The program shows x2 = 8635342404774617/9007199254740992
>
> Apparently, the correct and best result should be x2 = 209/218.
>
> Is anyone able to suggest a better solution?

```
using System;
using Google.OrTools.LinearSolver;
using Fractions;
public class GoogleLinearSolver
{
static void Main()
{

        Solver solver = Solver.CreateSolver("GLOP");
        Variable x1 = solver.MakeNumVar(0.0, double.PositiveInfinity, "x1");
        Variable x2 = solver.MakeNumVar(0.0, double.PositiveInfinity, "x2");
        Variable x3 = solver.MakeNumVar(0.0, double.PositiveInfinity, "x3");
        Variable x4 = solver.MakeNumVar(0.0, double.PositiveInfinity, "x4");
        Variable x5 = solver.MakeNumVar(0.0, double.PositiveInfinity, "x5");
    
        solver.Add(3 * x1 + 5 * x2 + 2 * x3 + 5 * x4 + 4 * x5 <= 36);
        solver.Add(7 * x1 + 12 * x2 + 11 * x3 + 10 * x4 <= 21);
        solver.Add(-3 * x2 + 12 * x3 + 7 * x4 + 2 * x5 <= 17);
    
        solver.Add(0 <= x1);
        solver.Add(0 <= x2);
        solver.Add(0 <= x3);
        solver.Add(0 <= x4);
        solver.Add(0 <= x5);
    
        solver.Add(x1 <= 20);
        solver.Add(x2 <= 20);
        solver.Add(x3 <= 20);
        solver.Add(x4 <= 20);
        solver.Add(x5 <= 20);
    
    
        solver.Maximize(141 * x1 + 393 * x2 + 273 * x3 + 804 * x4 + 175 * x5);
        Solver.ResultStatus resultStatus = solver.Solve();
    
        Fraction x1Fraction = Fraction.FromDouble(x1.SolutionValue()).Reduce();
        Fraction x2Fraction = Fraction.FromDouble(x2.SolutionValue()).Reduce();
        Fraction x3Fraction = Fraction.FromDouble(x3.SolutionValue()).Reduce();
        Fraction x4Fraction = Fraction.FromDouble(x4.SolutionValue()).Reduce();
        Fraction x5Fraction = Fraction.FromDouble(x5.SolutionValue()).Reduce();
        Fraction resultFract = Fraction.FromDouble(solver.Objective().Value()).Reduce();
    
    
        Console.WriteLine("========================================================================");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("   Solution: " + resultFract);
        Console.WriteLine("   x1 = " + x1Fraction);
        Console.WriteLine("   x2 = " + x2Fraction);
        Console.WriteLine("   x3 = " + x3Fraction);
        Console.WriteLine("   x4 = " + x4Fraction);
        Console.WriteLine("   x5 = " + x5Fraction);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("========================================================================");
    
    }

}
```

This code works but doesn't return the best solution, who can write better?

Comment: Why are you passing incorrect information to `MakeNumVar` and then trying to set per-variable bounds later using linear inequality constraints?  Just apply the ranges up-front.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain: The line `using Google.OrTools.LinearSolver;` tells you what `Solver` class is being used.

Comment: The answers you provide are equal to 14 decimal places.  What more do you need?  There is likely some numerical error down there in the decimal dust that is affecting the transformation back to a fraction.

Answer (score 0):

Simplex solvers are not numerically exact solvers. They always work with a given precision.

You can increase the precision, the fraction will be closer to the exact solution.

You can also use an exact simplex. For instance, glpk has an infinite precision mode.

They tend to be unusable, but you can try them.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this GLPK

```
var x1 >= 0 ;
var x2 >= 0 ;
var x3 >= 0 ;
var x4 >= 0 ;
var x5 >= 0 ;
maximize z: 141*x1 + 393*x2 + 273*x3 + 804*x4 + 175*x5;
subject to con1: 3*x1 + 5*x2 + 2*x3 + 5*x4 + 4*x5 <=36;
subject to con2: 7*x1 + 12*x2 + 11*x3 +10*x4 <=21;
subject to con3: -3*x2 +12*x3 + 7*x4 + 2*x5 <=17;
end;
```

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your answer from getting deleted.